# Remove space around an image flutter

Tags: flutter, stack

Hello im making an app where I have an image from the camera with a send button. Around the image is much space and if the image's height is less than the send button isnt at the bottom anymore. I need the image vertically centered and a maximun width. The Message container should be on the bottom.
Thanks for your help.

This is the code of my app:

```
return Scaffold( 
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, 
body: Stack( 
alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
 children: [ 
Image.file(widget.image,), 
Container( 
child: Row( 
children: [ 
Expanded( 
child: Container( 
margin: EdgeInsets.all(3), 
height: 50, 
child: TextField( 
controller: _writeMessageTextEditingController, 
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.white), 
decoration: InputDecoration( 
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 15,), 
border: OutlineInputBorder( 
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(300), 
borderSide: BorderSide( 
width: 0, 
style: 
BorderStyle.none, 
), 
), 
focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder( 
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(300), 
borderSide: BorderSide( 
width: 0, 
style: BorderStyle.none, 
), 
), 
filled: true, 
hintStyle: TextStyle( color: Colors.grey, ), 
hintText: "Message", 
fillColor: Colors.grey[800], 
), 
), 
), 
), 
Container( 
margin: EdgeInsets.all(3), 
height: 50, 
width: 50, 
decoration: BoxDecoration( 
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100), 
color: Color(0xff0077b6), 
), 
padding: EdgeInsets.all(8), 
child: GestureDetector( 
child: Icon(
Icons.send, 
color: Colors.white,
), 
onTap: (){ 
String message = _writeMessageTextEditingController.text.toString(); 
File file = widget.image; 
print(file); 
print(message); 
_writeMessageTextEditingController.clear(); 
Navigator.pop(context); 
//send message to server 
}, 
), 
), 
], 
), 
), 
], 
), 
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to start off, there are probably countless ways to achieve this. I opted to use `Column`s and their properties to align both of your stacked items.

#### The chat bar and send button

Let's start with the chat bar and send button. It essentially boils down to:

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [RowWithTextBarAndSendButton(...)],
),
```

Which ensures that your chat bar neatly aligns to the bottom of the screen. Moreover, I removed the `alignment` property in the stack, as that would not move the chat bar up when the keyboard opens to type, which doesn't make sense I think.

#### The image

Then for the image, I used another column (though especially here many options exist, I just like my columns), which looks like:

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Image(..., width: double.maxFinite,),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Note that giving the image a width `double.maxFinite` ensures it is centered horizontally when the width is less than your screen width.

#### What does that look like

For a normal image (high resolution) it centers the image vertically, and fills up the available space horizontally. If the keyboard is opened, the chat bar moves up, and the image is now centered in the remaining space. If the image is high enough the `stack` will cause the image to overlap a bit with the chat bar. If it's then not wide enough it will simply center horizontally. See the screenshots below:

[image: What it looks like by default]
[image: With the keyboard open]

Lastly for a small image, it centers it both horizontally and vertically.
[image: Small image example]

#### The code

For completeness, here's the code I used. For the image I used a network image but the same things should apply.

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            Expanded(child: Image.network('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg/1200px-Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg', width: double.maxFinite,),),
          ],),
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                  height: 50,
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _controller,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 15,),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(300),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          width: 0,
                          style:
                          BorderStyle.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(300),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          width: 0,
                          style: BorderStyle.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      hintStyle: const TextStyle( color: Colors.grey, ),
                      hintText: "Message",
                      fillColor: Colors.grey[800],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                  color: const Color(0xff0077b6),
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.send,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onTap: (){

                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```